# Python logging IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, logging

I have an application the sets up the logging using:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging_level, format=format_string, filename=log_file, filemode='a')
```

then call

```
logging.debug("My Message")
```

etc. to log messeages. This work fine in most of my application, but then for a particular module I get this error

```
File "C:\path\to\my\module\MyModule.py", line 53, in __init__
    logging.debug("__init__ called")
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1481, in debug
    root.debug(*((msg,)+args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1035, in debug
    if self.isEnabledFor(DEBUG):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1242, in isEnabledFor
    return level >= self.getEffectiveLevel()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1230, in getEffectiveLevel
    while logger:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this? Or where else to look to read up on it. I have already read through the logging module code and the python reference pages

Comment: whats the logging_level?

Comment: logging.DEBUG. I have verified this by adding logging.root.getEffectiveLevel() above it. It returns 10, which is logging.DEBUG

Comment: Very strange error message.  There's no list in that part of the logging module code.  I'd have to put it in a debugger.  By any chance is this a multi-threaded app?

Comment: What does your format string look like?

Comment: @mjhm It is but I get it in when in single threaded mode too

Comment: @Matt my format string is '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seems very wrong with your installation - it's hard to see how a line like

```
while logger:
```

would generate an `IndexError`.

So, delete all `.pyc` and `.pyo` files from your system (including in the stdlib folders) and try again. Ensure that none of your modules have the same name as any modules in the standard library.

Also, what version of Python are you using, and on which platform?

**Update:** If you are using embedded in a C++ program, or with C extensions, it's quite possible that some C or C++ code is clobbering memory, leading to the `IndexError` in a most unexpected place.

Can you reproduce in a pure-Python environment? If not, I fear the problem might be in the C/C++ code. It's also easier to clobber stuff in multi-threaded environments :-(

Comment: Python 2.6.5 on windows XP. Tried your suggestion, still got the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was an issue with the c++ side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Doug Helmann's site has [some guidance on using Python's logging module](http://pymotw.com/2/logging/index.html#module-logging).

There are also some examples to be downloaded there, which I haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read this and it does not help with my problem. I am leaning towards it being a bug in the python logging module now.

Comment: I take it you've not found anything your module that may be the cause then?

Comment: What's the full version number of Python? If it's less than 2.6.6, try updating, and see if you still hit it.

Comment: It is Python 2.6.5 however I am tied to this due to the a C++ program that is currently compiled again the 2.6.5 DLL